# Image not properly displayed

Tags: java

I am trying to realize a simple splash screen. Therefore, I have two classes, `Loader` which is a child of `JFrame` and `Background` (a child of `JComponent`, used as `GlassPane`) to hold the actual image. And below this image there should be a small progress bar.

I am displaying the window as soon as the image is loaded. This works just fine. But it won't display the image. The Scrollbar takes the whole frame. If I am manually minifying the window and bring it back to front, the image will be displayed.

Why is the image not displayed immediately?

Here's the code:

**Loader**

```
public class Loader extends JFrame{

    private static final int _WIDTH  = 500;
    private static final int _HEIGHT = 300;

    private JProgressBar bar;
    private Background bg;

    public Loader (){
        super("Risiko Loader");
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        Dimension window = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setBounds(window.width / 2 - _WIDTH / 2, window.height / 2 - _HEIGHT / 2, _WIDTH, _HEIGHT);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f));
        this.setFocusableWindowState(true);

        this.setIcons();

        bar = new JProgressBar();

        bar.setSize(_WIDTH, 20);
        bar.setLocation(0, _HEIGHT - 20);
        bar.setValue(0);
        bar.setMinimum(0);
        bar.setMaximum(100);

        this.add(bar);

        bg = new Background();
        this.setGlassPane(this.bg);
        this.bgIsReady();
    }

    private void bgIsReady(){
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }while(this.bg.tracker.statusID(1, false) == MediaTracker.COMPLETE);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
        this.getGlassPane().repaint();
        bar.setValue(50);
    }

    private void setIcons(){
        ArrayList<Image> icons = new ArrayList<>();
        icons.add(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "icon16.png"));
        icons.add(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "icon32.png"));
        this.setIconImages(icons);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Loader l = new Loader();
    }
}
```

And **Background**

```
public class Background extends JComponent{
    private Image img;

    public MediaTracker tracker;

    public Background(){
        this.tracker =  new MediaTracker(this);
        String imgPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "images" + File.separator + "splash.png";
        this.img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imgPath);
        this.tracker.addImage(this.img, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(this.tracker.statusID(1, false) == MediaTracker.LOADING) {//not loaded
            return;
        }
        // Draw the background image
        g.drawImage(this.img, 1, 1, null);
        System.out.println("p");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably this part -

```
do {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }catch(Exception e){}
}while(this.bg.tracker.statusID(1, false) == MediaTracker.COMPLETE);
```

You should probably be checking for `MediaTracker.LOADING` in the `while` instead of `MediaTracker.COMPLETE`. What's probably happening now is that the code sleeps for 100ms, checks the `MediaTracker` status, and it's still `MediaTracker.LOADING`, which isn't `COMPLETE`, so the code goes ahead and sets your frame, glassPane, etc. visible without the image being loaded first.  Loading your image must be taking longer than 100ms - otherwise your problem would be that your frame never shows up.

On another note - if you're trying to make "a simple splash screen" - this is way over complicated.

There's a built-in [SplashScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) class in Java 1.6+.

Even if you wanted to recreate this yourself you could just use a `JFrame` with `BorderLayout`, put a `JLabel` with an`ImageIcon` of your image in `BorderLayout.CENTER`, and put the `JProgressBar` in `BorderLayout.SOUTH` as a much simpler option.

Comment: thanks. unfortunatly the `MediaTracker.LOADING`-part didn't change anything i switched to your `BorderLayout` solution and it worked perfectly. thanks.